# Why is my program hanging on a system.out.print of DatagramPacket.getData()

Tags: java, udp, linked-list, packet, datagram

```
LinkedList<DatagramPacket> queue = new LinkedList<DatagramPacket>();

for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println("1: This prints.");
    System.out.println("2: This doesn't: " + new String(queue.get(i).getData()));
    int start = (new String(queue.get(i).getData())).indexOf("\r\n") + "\r\n".length();
    data.concat(new String(queue.get(i).getData()).substring(start));
}
```

We're trying to take all the data from `queue`, the list of packets, and put them all into one string.

But whenever it gets to the 2nd `println` (which is the same as the line below it) the program hangs and doesn't do anything.

Without the `getData()` the print works. eg.

```
System.out.printlin("2: This doesn't: " +  new String(queue.get(i)));
```

Also, whenever I add a packet to the queue, I immediately print the last packet in the queue, and that works.

```
public void addPacket(DatagramPacket additional)
{
    queue.add(additional);
    System.out.println("1: " + new String(queue.getLast().getData()));
}
```

Comment: guess, no data yet came from cold^W, network

Comment: I've already received the packet and printed it before adding it to the queue, but now when we retrieve it, it does nothing. It doesn't return null, it just hangs the program.

Comment: make thread dump and examine where thread which calls `getData` has stuck, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the `DatagramPacket` class, but this certainly fixes some performance problems related to `String` manipulation and `LinkedList.get`. It might just be that your program runs really slowly?

```
StringBuilder dataBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
Iterator<DatagramPacket> queueIter = queue.iterator();
while(queueIter.hasNext()) {
  DatagramPacket next = queueIter.next();
  System.out.println("1: This prints.");
  System.out.println("2: This doesn't: " + new String(next.getData()));
  int start = (new String(next.getData())).indexOf("\r\n") + "\r\n".length();
  dataBuilder.append(new String(next.getData()).substring(start));
}
data = dataBuilder.toString();
```

---

What if you tried this:

```
public class Foo {
  // instead of LinkedList<DatagramPacket>
  public LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>(); 
  public void addPacket(DatagramPacket additional) {
      queue.add(new String(additional.getData()));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't with the performance, the program hangs on the very first `getData()`.

Comment: Both. I put the print in to test, so technically the first one that says "This doesn't print"

Comment: Well, clearly the problem is not your posted code snippet then, it's something about the network communications. I would still make these posted changes, though :)

Comment: After I add a packet to the queue, I immediately print out the last packet in the queue, which should be the one I just added, and it is. I added the code for adding to the original post.